# How to achieve that only a specified number of events are in the system (using simmer R package)?

Tags: r, simulation, event-simulation

I simply want to model a machine repair System.
Input: 5 machines that trigger the down-events, 2 repair men dealing with the down-events

Note: once a machine is down (not working due to failure), the add_generator function shall not generate "down events" anymore, because the machine is already down/broken (and hence cannot produce any down-events!).

Here is my simple approach so far (it works, but without the limitation mentioned above):

````
```
library(simmer)

set.seed(42)

env <- simmer("andi_simu") %>% add_global("cnt",0)
env

cnt<-0
NUM_MACHINES<-6 # equals: max. number of down machines! (obviously)
BREAK_MEAN<-1/20 # 20 = MTTF
NUM_ENGINEERS<-3
REPAIR_TIME<-1.3 # in hours
engineers <- paste0("engineer", 1:NUM_ENGINEERS-1)

downevent <- trajectory("downevents' path") %>%
    ## add an intake activity 
    select(engineers, policy = "random") %>%
    set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(env)}) %>%
    seize_selected(1) %>%
    log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(env) - get_attribute(env, "start_time"))}) %>%
    timeout(function() rexp(1,REPAIR_TIME)) %>%
    release_selected(1)

for (i in engineers) env %>%
  add_resource(i, 1, 0) #, preemptive = TRUE) %>%

env %>%
  add_generator("downevent",downevent,function() rexp(1,BREAK_MEAN*NUM_MACHINES))

env %>% 
  run(80) %>%
  now()


result <-
  env %>%
  get_mon_arrivals() %>%
  transform(waiting_time = end_time - start_time - activity_time)

print(paste("Mean waiting time: ", mean(result$waiting_time)))
```
````

Would appreciate every hint how to do it!
Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: Hey Andreas82, maybe have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on asking questions. Your question seems too broad.

Comment: Ok, maybe I did not explain well enough: main point is that the "add_generator()" function generates "downevents/failures" with respective distribution. - What I need: the "failures" shall be generated, but only if the number of failures does not exceed the number of machines (that actually trigger those failures). This is not specified in the Simmer R help ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would setup an additional resource with `capacity=NUM_MACHINES` and `queue_size=0` to ensure that there is only one active failure per machine (additional events just will be discarded). Of course, you must seize this resource *before* seizing an engineer.